# How can i draw a Square in HTML5 Canvas at run time?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am working on a HTML5 Project.There is a drawing graphics API to draw Rectangle (fillRectStrokeRect).But how can i draw a SQUARE. I have tried the following way to draw it
**CODE**

```
getMouse(e);
x2=mx; y2=my;
var width=endX-startX;
var height=endY-startY;

annCanvasContext.beginPath();
annCanvasContext.lineWidth=borderWidth;
var centerX=width/2;
var centerY=width/2;
var radius=width/2;
annCanvasContext.arc(centerX+5, centerY+5, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
annCanvasContext.stroke();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `fillRect` or `strokeRect` with the width and height being equal.

```
var x = 0, y = 0,
    side = 10;

ctx.fillRect(x, y, side, side);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/amaan/BQZtB/)

As you say in the comments, if you want to fit the largest square in a circle, it's more Math related than about code. I'll trying explaining it to you, but you'll probably find better, more visual explanations elsewhere on the Internet.

Draw the diameter of the circle in a way that it divides your square into two equal parts. Now one part is a right angled triangle, which has two of its sides equal. We know the diameter. Using the Pythogorean theorem, you get this equation: 
`side^2 + side^2 = diameter^2`.

Let's find the side now.

`2(side^2) = diameter^2`
`side^2 = (diameter^2)/2`
`side = Math.sqrt( (diameter^2)/2 )`

Now, to turn this into code.

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d'),
    radius = 20;

ctx.canvas.addEventListener('click', function (e){
    ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
    ctx.arc(e.pageX, e.pageY, radius, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    var diameter = radius * 2;
    var side = Math.sqrt( (diameter * diameter)/2 );
    ctx.fillRect(e.pageX - side/2, e.pageY - side/2, side, side);
    ctx.closePath();
}, false);
```

This would draw a square inside a circle wherever you click on the canvas.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/amaan/H5Tcu/)

Comment: Thanks Amaan. But i want to draw circle inside a square at run time.

Comment: @Shanky Added that to the answer.

Comment: Amaan its working for me, but i have a little more query how can i make a circle at runtime, with varying radius.

Comment: @Shanky Just change the `radius` and `diameter` variables!

Comment: thats the real issue which i am facing now. How can i calculate radius at run time (According to height or width)

Comment: See how I got how to find the `side`? Manipulate the equation. You should get this: `radius = Math.sqrt(2(side^2))/2`

Comment: We have "radius = Math.sqrt(2(side^2))/2" to calculate radius, but we are calculating side by the radius. Its a vice versa case.i have tried it. but i am not getting the calculation for this task. Actually I want to draw a circle containing a square outside it at run time.

Comment: @Shanky What the are you trying to do? Either the side or the radius *have* to be fixed. You said you want to calculate the raduys according to the height or width. The height / width of a square is the side. Make the side variable whatever you want and then calculate the radius

Comment: thanks for answer but could you explain me it a little bit more in demo that how can in  draw a square at runtime.